# Run/End or Disable/Enable a task in scheduler in windows using Ansible

Tags: windows, ansible, windows-task-scheduler

I have a task already created in Task scheduler on a windows machine, which runs everyday at 5AM.

In case I want to run in some other time, without changing in the task scheduler but from Ansible( when the playbook runs). How can it be done?
Similarly, if I want to End the Task in the scheduler, how can it be done?

For enable and disable, the below one works.

```
- name: Disable a task that already exists
  win_scheduled_task:
    name: TaskToDisable
    enabled: no
```

Please advise.

Answer (score 1):

I used the powershell commands and this works.

```
win_shell: Start-ScheduledTask -TaskName {{task}}
win_shell: Stop-ScheduledTask -TaskName {{task}}
```

Comment: Simple as that. It works for me.